# How to convert h265 videos to h264 videos on pi2

Tags: kodi, pi-2, osmc

I have raspberry pi 2 with osmc/Kodi installed on it, I have several h265 videos on it which can't be played smoothly. I would like to convert them to h264 using some conversion tool or package that should be installed on pi. Can someone please advise which package and how to use it to achieve the conversion ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of `ffmpeg` to convert h265 format to h264 format.

1. Install `ffmpeg` using command `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
2. Download h265 codecs. `wget http://ftp.videolan.org/pub/videolan/x265/x265_1.7.tar.gz`
3. Install dependencies for compilation. `sudo apt-get install cmake cmake-curses-gui build-essential yasm`
4. untar it by `tar -xvzf x265_1.7.tar.gz`
5. `cd x265_1.7/build/linux`
6. `./make-Makefiles.bash` It will ask you for cmake option. Press `c` to configure and `g` to generate and exit
7. `make` to compile them
8. `sudo make install` to install libx265 to default `lib` path

Now that we have `ffmpeg` and `libx265` installed. To convert just video,
`ffmpeg -i <input-file> -an -x265-params crf=25 <output-file.mp4>`
To convert with audio,
`ffmpeg -i <input-file> -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 <output-file.mp4>`

Please note that, it takes a decent amount of time to convert on x86_64 architecture. Converting it natively on Rpi will take about 4 - 5 x amount of time.

For more details : Read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/785528/how-to-generate-an-mp4-with-h-265-codec-using-ffmpeg)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me, except before step 6, I edited `source/CMakeLists.txt`:
(a) line 10 ->  OLD->NEW `cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW)`
(b) line 16 -> OLD->NEW `cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)`
(c) line 48 -> remove `include(Version)` and replace with (i don't think the actual numbers functionally matter):
`set(X265_VERSION "3.5")`
`set(X265_LATEST_TAG "3.5")`
`set(X265_TAG_DISTANCE "0")`
`message(STATUS "X265 RELEASE VERSION ${X265_VERSION}")`

Comment: I also downloaded master from https://github.com/videolan/x265/